# SQL Server 2005 Installation on Windows 2000 Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-server-2000

We want to install sql server 2005 on Windo
ws 2000 Server. We are able to install database service engine, analysis services engine and integration services.

But we are unable to install workstation components like SSMS.

Does anybody faced this problem?
What is the fix for this?

Thanks,
Raghu

Comment: Do you get an error when you are attempting to install them?

Comment: I do not get any error while installing it. But I do get some warning messages when setup runs some rules to check whether system matches the requirement or not. One is SP1 of IE 6 is not available and minimum hardware requirement is not met. 
I checked whether C:/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/90/tools/Binn/VSShell/IDE contains SqlWb.exe file. It does not. I did what is mentioned in this blog http://blog.ralfelt.com/post/Microsoft-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-Missing.aspx. Still no success.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have SP4 installed on the server, that's a prerequisite.

Answer (score 1):

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6102265.html

follow the link instruction given